# Get Value from SwiftUI Color Picker

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

iOS 14 shipped with native color pickers for UIKit ([`UIColorWell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorwell)), AppKit ([`NSColorWell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolorwell)) and SwiftUI ([`ColorPicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/colorpicker)).

While the color wells have a property `selectedColor` that exposes the selected `UIColor`/`NSColor` values, the SwiftUI `ColorPicker` takes a `Binding<Color>`. However, I can't find any information how to get anything useful from the `Color` value.

Creating a `Color` from a `UIColor` is easy using [`Color.init(_: UIColor)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:)-9rl8m) but there does not seem to be a way to get a `UIColor` from an existing `Color` or to extract the color components (e.g. the RGB values similar to the [`UIColor.getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred) method).

How do I get the underlying color values from a SwiftUI `ColorPicker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In majority of cases you use `Color` in SwiftUI directly, ie it is not needed to extract anything from it.

Anyway if it is needed to have `UIColor` SwiftUI 2.0 provides new API for that

> ```
> extension UIColor {
>
>     @available(iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
>     @available(OSX, unavailable)
>     public convenience init(_ color: Color)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
extension Color {
    struct Components {
        var r, g, b, a: Double
    }
    
    var components: Components? {
        guard let components = UIColor(self).cgColor.components?.compactMap(Double.init),
              components.count == 4
        else { return nil}
        return Components(r: components[0], g: components[1], b: components[2], a: components[3])
    }
}
// Usage
print(Color.primary.components)
```